# Blur on contenteditable div on ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, contenteditable, blur

If you would have worked with contenteditable divs on ipad, you would have found that the blur event does not get register.

A quick hack is provided in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer has its source here: https://gist.github.com/shimondoodkin/1081133
Basically, we create an input element which can register blur properly and change focus to it and then blur it, whenever the contenteditable div is supposed to blur. I have tweaked shimondoodkin's solution to work perfectly, with proper positioning of the input element so that the page does not scroll abruptly while attempting to focus the input element.

```
if(/AppleWebKit\/([\d.]+)/.exec(navigator.userAgent)) {
    function getPos(el) {
      for (var lx=0, ly=0; el != null; lx += el.offsetLeft, ly += el.offsetTop, el = el.offsetParent) return {x: lx,y: ly};
    }

    var refocus_prevtarget = null, inp = ce("input", "", document.body); inp.setAttribute("tabIndex","-1"); inp.style.cssText = "width:1px; height:1px; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; position:fixed";
    function refocusContentEditable(e) { 
        var curelement=getEvtSrc(e);
        if(refocus_prevtarget) { // if we have a previous element
            // if previous element was contentEditable and the next isn't then:
            if(refocus_prevtarget.contentEditable == 'true' && curelement.contentEditable !== 'true') {
                var p = getPos(refocus_prevtarget); inp.style.left = p.x; inp.style.top = p.y; // change the position of the input element to near the last elem
                inp.focus(); inp.blur(); // set caret focus to input el that handles blur correctly
                curelement.focus(); // focus the wanted element
            }
        }
        refocus_prevtarget=curelement;
    }
    aeh(document.body, "touchend", refocusContentEditable); // add global click handler
}
```